# Sort the elements of this list according to their length frequency in Clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(defn lfsort [list](mapcat  #(if (sequential? %) % [%]) 
                              (sort-by count (vals (group-by count list)))))
```

Today in a seminar we were going over the function above, that if given, `(lfsort '((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o)))` outputs:

```
((i j k l)
 (o)
 (a b c)
 (f g h)
 (d e)
 (d e)
 (m n))
```

We started by programming a function that sorts it in length order using,

```
(defn sort [list] (sort-by count list))
```

outputting:

```
((o)
 (d e)
 (d e)
 (m n)
 (a b c)
 (f g h)
 (i j k l))
```

I understand how the sort function works, but I'm still not sure about how the lfsort does, could someone help dumb it down for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about a language that emphasises interactive programming at the REPL is that you can very easily experiment with all the little parts that make up your function.

First define `list` to be your data.

```
(def list '((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o)))
```

Then evaluate the forms in your `lfsort` function (the only argument to which is conveniently named `list`). Start by evaluating the innermost forms and then gradually expand until you have evaluated the entire function body. Use `doc` on all built-in functions, and experiment!

So:

```
(group-by count list)
; => {3 [(a b c) (f g h)], 2 [(d e) (d e) (m n)], 4 [(i j k l)], 1 [(o)]}
```

… now we have a map of counts to the lists of size ‘count’ …

```
(vals (group-by count list))
; => ([(a b c) (f g h)] [(d e) (d e) (m n)] [(i j k l)] [(o)])
```

… now we have a seq of just the values of the map (each of the value vectors containing lists of equal size) …

```
(sort-by count (vals (group-by count list)))
; => ([(i j k l)] [(o)] [(a b c) (f g h)] [(d e) (d e) (m n)])
```

… now the vectors in the seq are ordered by how many lists are in them …

```
(mapcat #(if (sequential? %) % [%])
  (sort-by count (vals (group-by count list))))
;; => ((i j k l) (o) (a b c) (f g h) (d e) (d e) (m n))
```

… finally the lists are unpacked from the vectors and flattened into a simple seq. The lists in the seq are now ordered, with those lists whose sizes occur least frequently at the front.

That last `mapcat` operation could be expressed more simply with `(apply concat ,,,)`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can simplify to

```
(defn lfsort [coll]
  (apply concat 
   (sort-by count (vals (group-by count coll)))))
```

... since `sequential?` always returns `true`.

We can re-state this as

```
(defn lfsort [coll]
  (->> coll
       (group-by count)
       vals
       (sort-by count)
       (apply concat)))
```

... using the `->>` thread-last macro.

So this function

- takes its argument `coll`,
- groups its collection elements by `count`,
- discards the keys, mapping to the vector values,
- sorts these vectors by length, and finally
- concatenates the vectors.